# Changing decimal positions with sql query

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I need to change `HSS2.5X.25 to HSS2.500X.250`  in Designation.

Data-Type of `designation is nvarchar` in the table.

I was trying to do it like this..

```
    UPDATE  [AISC14-HSS-ROUND] 
    SET Designation = convert(DECIMAL(2,3),Designation);
```

which is giving an error like...
The operation cannot be performed because the scale of the numeric data types do not match.

is there any way to convert this..?

Comment: That is not a decimal number, so it's little wonder it doesn't work. You may have to do this by cutting up the values... not sure whether the database engine is the ideal candidate for the job

Answer (score 0):

Start with this

```
declare @n nvarchar(100)
set @n='HSS2.5X.25'

select part1+'.'+replace(part2,'X',replicate('0',4-len(part2))+'X')+'.'+left(part3+'000',3) from
(
select parsename(@n,3) as part1,parsename(@n,2) as part2 ,parsename(@n,1) as part3
) as t
```